# How can I download the video from blob URL in genvideos.io

Tags: video, video-streaming, blob

I read the way to download the video after I get m3u8 url from Developer Tool in Chrome.
But I can't this url (m3u8 url).

Comment: Your link `genvideos.io` doesn't work for me (in the UK). It shows a text warning about court / legal action against the site and that it's currently blocked. Just letting you know that other helpers may not be able to test your problem in action.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to download any blob file:

Here is an easy hack I did:

1. Go to the developer code inspection (right-click>>inspect)
2. Toggle the page from HTML WEB... to any Apple device.
3. Refresh Page.
4. In the new Apple device viewing, start playing the video
5. right-click>>inspect on the video
6. Search the div which contains the video
7. Right-click scr=" " link... and select "Open in new tab"
8. Go to new tab and right-click on the video and select "Save video as..."

No extensions, no playlist crap, no complicated stuff.
Just inspect the HTML as an Apple device.

You're welcome. ;)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The src is still "blob:https://---.----.com/9ffe9354-3a54-4c8b-94c4-40ce9286da56" and opening it in new tab still not working

Comment: It worked for me. Amazing answer. Just Go to developer view (F12), then, change to any apple iPhone device (say, iPhone X) (or click Ctrl+Shift+M directly after clicking F12), from where we check the responsiveness of a website. Then, go to the video, you will get multiple options: (1) Copy video URL (normal URL from where you can download) and, (2) Save video as (again from where you can download).

Comment: Can't believe this worked.